# How to make facebook login works with firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook-login

i'm using firebase and i'm trying to implement facebook login. When i'm tapping on the button, i get this error

> App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].

But, my app id is set into the info.plist. I have checked and all is set fine.

```
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb45xxxxxxxx</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>4524xxxxxxxxxx</string>
  <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
  <string>Licenta</string>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbapi20160328</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug on this:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1745

You can use version <= 9.1.0 until they fix this.
If using CocoaPods, add this lines to your Podfile and then run "pod update":

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 9.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 9.1.0'
```